# The directory 'var/di' doesn't exist - skipping cleanup

Tags: magento2

I ran the 'php bin/magento setup:upgrade' command and received this error. Can you tell why the command line shows this error? I am new to Magento 2 and had previous experience with Magento 1.

Comment: It might be permission issue. Please create var/di directory and give proper permission to that folder else give full permission to var folder.

Comment: First Run : sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ or chmod -R 777 var/ pub/

& after run : php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: I don't think there's a permission issue as I had cleared manually all the folders inside the `var` folder. All other folders had been created, but this one shows warning when running the command `setup:upgrade`

Comment: This message is logged during deletion of contents.  This message is just an info level log; not a warning or error.

Comment: I think that you are using magento 2.1

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but `var/di` folder created by default when we run `bin/magento setup:di:compile`. 
In your case plaese run the `bin/magento setup:di:compile` and check the `var/di` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below commands and check:

```
rm -rf var/* generation/*
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Also check your permission to var and generation folder.